# Excel, Cumulative Summing every Nth row but random lengths of N

Tags: excel, random, excel-formula, sum, cumulative-sum

I am trying to do a cumulative sum every Nth row on Excel however I am not what N could be as it is random and depends on other factors. I will attach a photo to show a simple clear example of what I mean.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Q2:

```
=IF(OR(P2="-",Q1="-"),P2,P2+Q1)
```

then copy down the column.

[image]